# Deploying to tomcat with ant: how to know when the application is reloaded?

Tags: tomcat, deployment, ant

The current ant build process of my Spring MVC application, deployed to tomcat 7, is the following (each step is a target):

1. put the website in maintenance mode (this instructs nginx on the server to show a static "maintenance" page instead of loading the tomcat application)
2. copy the war to the web server, under the webapps directory
3. wait for tomcat to have reloaded the application
4. put the site back to production mode (i.e., reverting point 1)

My problem is target 3; I have to manually watch the output of `tail -f /var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out` until it shows the message saying that the application is reloaded. Then I have to manually launch the target doing point 4.

Is there a way for ant itself to parse the output of `tail -f` and, if and when a certain message shows up, stop task number 3 and go on to number 4 automatically?

NB: I still would like to see the output of `tail -f` in the console (if there are errors, the debug information is useful), I just would like it to stop and go onto the next target if everything loads up correctly.

EDIT:

a little update to say that I found a satisfying solution after all. The following ant target will tail the catalina.out file, printing the lines in the console and quitting the command when the words "Servlet context initialized" appear in the output (this is a message that my application prints to the System output when it is initialized).

```
<target name="tail catalina.out DEV until restart" depends="Get credentials for DEV">
    <property name="tailtime" value="4" />
    <sshexec host="${dev}" username="${username}" password="${password}" command="echo ${password}| sudo -S tail --lines=1 -f /var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out | while read LOGLINE; do echo &quot;${LOGLINE}&quot;;  [[ &quot;${LOGLINE}&quot; == *&quot;Servlet context initialized&quot;* ]] &amp;&amp; echo ${password}|sudo -S pkill -u root tail; done" failonerror="false" trust="true" />
</target>
```

So, after this target is run, I know the application is up, and I can fire the next target that puts the site in production mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very hack-ish way to solve this would be something like that:

1. I'm don't know how to do it in Spring, but could you create some simple bean and force it to initialize after everything heavy-load is done successfully.  That bean could just touch some file (e.g. /run/shm/reload-nginx).
2. Every time /run/shm/reload-nginx modify date changes, inotify triggers your script, e.g. via http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait

Comment: Thanks, this is a good idea until I find a cleaner way to do it.